# How can I force a URL to have "www." no matter what?

Tags: url, web, joomla, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1. It might seem like a weird question but I need my URL to have "www." written in the URL at all times. If the URL doesn't have "www." then the cart functions don't work. If it does have it, then it does work.

Is there a way I can force this? I am using Parallels Plesk 10.3.1 if I can do it on there.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Comment: I know about this already. This wasn't a specific Joomla question though

Comment: No problem. :) But maybe you could omit mentioning Joomla and Virtuemart from question and tags if it wasn't directly related.

Comment: I'll remember in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your server is running on apache, you can add a .htaccess file to your root webdirectory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! Call me silly but how can I check what its running on through Plesk?

Comment: Just found out its CentOS. Can this be done on there?

Comment: I don't know plesk, but if you create this file and there is no server error most likely its apache there. or check with a php script which contains: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` there should be all the information you want. edit: yeah sorry, the OS doesn't matter, its the webserver like nginx or apache etc. which is important

Comment: Can the file be done on Linux as well? Since I think CentOS is Linux which the server runs on

Comment: it doesn't matter what OS there is, as long as the webserver is Apache, which uses this `.htaccess` files. most of my setups are linux with Apache webservers and everything works fine there

Comment: I've got an htaccess.txt file which Joomla made. I tried adding it on there, but it didn't work.

Comment: your file should be named `.htaccess` without the .txt extension (its a hidden file on linux (it starts with a dot)), oh, have a look at: https://secure.jabsupport.com/billing/knowledgebase/69/How-do-htaccess-files-work-in-Plesk.html